# Angular 15: Class NgOptimizedImage is not an Angular module

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular15

I have recently upgraded project to Angular 15. Seems to work fine.
Also, I'm trying to implement `NgOptimizedImage` from `@angular/common` based on **Step 1** from official docs
https://angular.io/api/common/NgOptimizedImage , however  it fails on the first step:

Step 1 <*states*>: import the NgOptimizedImage directive.

```
import { NgOptimizedImage } from '@angular/common';

// Include it into the necessary NgModule
@NgModule({
  imports: [NgOptimizedImage],
})
class AppModule {}

// ... or a standalone Component
@Component({
  standalone: true
  imports: [NgOptimizedImage],
})
class MyStandaloneComponent {}
```

The IntelliJ IDEA underlines my implementation (the image below) and complains: **Class NgOptimizedImage is not an Angular module**
Why?
[image]

However, if I click on NgOptimizedImage on line 32 (highlighted on the image above), I appear right inside myprojectname\node_modules@angular\common\index.d.ts
right on the

```
export declare class NgOptimizedImage implements OnInit, OnChanges, OnDestroy {
```

which proves it's found.

Any ideas why it complains and how to fix that?

ng version:

```
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1502.6
@angular-devkit/build-angular   15.2.6
@angular-devkit/core            15.2.6
@angular-devkit/schematics      15.2.6
@angular/cli                    15.2.6
.........................................
rxjs                            6.5.5
typescript                      4.8.4
webpack                         5.80.0
```

Comment: Weird issue, did you restart your IDE ? Does the CLI throw an error at compile time ?

Comment: Probably you have to remove your node_modules and run npm install again because currently, I tried to use that module in angular 15.1.2, and works right. [stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ohjkdx?file=src%2Fmain.ts).

Comment: IDE was restarted. No errors at compile time, compiles successfully. Node_modules were removed, npm i executed from scratch. Still highlighted.